# Silverlight 4 Datagrid, Set RowBackground

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datagrid

I know that the data grid isn't designed to directly access each row. My problem is I need to highlight rows based on certain conditions but not just at loading time. After the grid has been loaded there can be changes that occur on a collection that is not the collection that the grid is populated from so changes to this collection obviously won't affect the grid.

Sample Data Diagram:

```
[GridCollection]             [SecondaryCollection]
{ID = 0, Name = "Test A"}    {ID = 0, GridCollectionID = 0, Name = "Test A Linked"}
{ID = 1, Name = "Test B"}
```

So in this case GridCollection item 0 would be highlighted in the grid. But if I add another item to the SecondaryCollection this item would be should highlighted in the grid.

Now I can force an update to the grid's ItemsSource but this seems hacky. Anyone got any ideas on how to approach this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be really easy to achieve by using [Prism's](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458915.aspx):

1. Make sure the items in GridCollection implement INotifyPropertyChanged
2. Add a boolean IsHighlight property to the class of items in GridCollection
3. When an item is added to SecondaryCollection, fire an event using the event aggregator, using the GridCollectionID as payload.
4. Subscribe to this event on GridCollection and set IsHighlight to true.
5. On the DataGrid, set your conditional format to be on when IsHighlight is true.

This methodology is decoupled and robust and it let's you make the highlight look as you want and change any time, even using animations.